# Some issues page has a querystring while using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, query-string

I have some problem ajax with query string, I can send the data if page does not have and `Info.aspx/Save` works great. But when I fill somethings with query string then post same data it will return http 500 error. I have nothing with querystring in javascript I use it in C# for id.

```
 var data = '{name: "' + $("input[name$='name']").val() +
                    '",description: "' + $("input[name$='description']").val() +
                    '",code: "' + $("input[name$='code']").val() +'"}';
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Info.aspx/Save",
                data: data,
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var result = data.d
                    console.log(result)
                    if (result > 0)
                        success.show();
                    else
                        error.show();
                    Metronic.scrollTo(error, -200);

                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('err')
                }
            });

    [WebMethod]
    public static int Save(string name, string description, string code)
    {
        ClassInfo classInfo = new ClassInfo();
        return ClassInfo.Save(name, code, description, FileInfo.id);
    }
```

I just use querystring in C# for filling inputs. Altough I send same data it works without querystring inpgae's adressbar, If it has querystring in addressbar ajax returns me http500 error and `Save` `WebMethod` does not work.

Comment: The question is incomplete, how are u sending data?? If say u are trying to send as name value pair, it has to be a json object, it can't be the same as when you call with URL.

Comment: I added something, these are what you mean?

Comment: @user4065706 - use **`JSON.stringify(data);`**

Answer (score 1):

`data` types must be `object`, no string.

```
var data = {name: $("input[name$='name']").val() ,description:$("input[name$='description']").val(),code:$("input[name$='code']").val()};
```

Remove the contentType or change it to

```
"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
```

Then

```
$.post('/Info.aspx/Save',data , 
   function (data) {   
});
```

Or

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Info.aspx/Save',
    data: data 
});
```

Server side
Your json parameter names must be same with the c# paramter names.

```
[WebMethod(true)]
public static string Save(string name, string description, string code)
{
    return name+" "+description+" "+code;
}
```

Usable for `Web Method` and `Query String`(working for both)
The query string parameters need to be passed as JSON.

```
data: JSON.stringify({ "name": "name", "description": "description","code":"code" }),
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

Server side

```
[WebMethod(true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static String Save(string name, string description, string code)
{
}
```

Comment: I coaught the paramaters in `webmethod Save(string name, string description, string code)`.
and I used querystring for pageloading. Is it working for both?

Comment: It's a web service so parameters wouldn't be passed in the Querystring.  The first line of code you give him would solve his problem - no need for the rest as it's incorrect or guiding him the wrong way.

Comment: @Archer ``url: "Info.aspx/Save"`` is it a ``web service`` ? for ``web service`` data must be ``JSON.stringify(data)``.

Comment: `[WebMethod(true)]` Just this is enough for my code. thanks (:

Comment: Sorry - of course it's not a web service - my bad.  But if he wants to pass the data as parameters, as in this question, then he simply passes an object and jQuery will do the work for him, so converting it is not required.